# I am creating a to do list using javascript. I want to make it so that when the check box is check/unchecked it adds/removes a class

Tags: javascript

I am creating a to do list using javascript.

The to do list has input field that creates a div with a checkbox, the text I entered, and a delete button.

I want to make it so that when the check box is check/unchecked it adds/removes a class.

Answer (score 0):

Get the element using getElementById,then alter the element's class using className.

```
let someElement = document.getElementById('some-elem');
    if(condition)
        someElement.className += ' class';
```

Comment: This will replace the whole class. Think about using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which has `add` and `remove` methods which would be more in line with what the OP is asking for.